# How do I fix an ambigous funciton call in `<deque>`

Tags: c++

So one of my files that most files include defines the function:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T & a, T & b)
{
    T t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}
```

And this is producing an error from `<deque>` saying that a call to std::swap in `<bits/move.h>` is ambiguous; is there a way to bring std::swap into my namespace without pulling in anything else to resolve this?

I tried `#define swap std::swap` but that just resulted in the error `std::std::swap undeclared` in`<deque>`

Comment: What compiler are you using? Can you provide a minimal test case that we can use to confirm this?

Comment: How about if you just *don't* define this function yourself, and include `<algorith>` or `<utility>` where you need to use a `swap`?

Comment: Yeah, if you make a template swap as in the example, and that swap isn't part of your standard library, its going to conflict with EVERYTHING.

Comment: Put your `swap` in its own namespace.

Comment: The namespace is not going to help a lot. Look up the rules for Argument Dependent Lookup aka ADL. It's going to pull in functions from the namespace of any of the *arguments*

Comment: I guess @JerryCoffin has the best idea, but I wish there were a better solution, because I know this sort of thing will crop up again.

Comment: Is there any reason that you *are* defining a custom `swap` function rather than using `std::swap` anyway?

Comment: You could make an ADL barrier, but *why* do you have this in the first place?

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` all over the place?

Comment: @ZanLynx You are mistaken that namespacing will not help. Putting a function in a namespace by itself will prevent it from being found by ADL; if it's in a namespace by itself then there are no types in that namespace, then an argument can never have a type from the same namespace as the function, so ADL will never find it.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]? But seriously, remove that function.